# WM_CHAR and strange characters with Alt-key

Tags: winapi, mfc

I have an MFC `CWnd` derived text editor and when I (accidentally) press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>, `WM_CHAR` inserts a character '☺'.
Spy++ logs (I can't copy/paste - I had to type this):

```
WM_SYSKEYDOWN nVirtKey:VK_MENU cRepeat:1 ScanCode:38 fExtended:0 AltDown:1 fRepeat:0 fUp:0
WM_SYSKEYDOWN nVirtKey:VK_MENU cRepeat:1 ScanCode:38 fExtended:0 AltDown:1 fRepeat:1 fUp:0
WM_SYSKEYDOWN nVirtKey:'A'     cRepeat:1 ScanCode:1  fExtended:0 AltDown:1 fRepeat:0 fUp:0
WM_SYSCHAR    chCharCode:97    cRepeat:1 ScanCode:1E fExtended:0 AltDown:1 fRepeat:0 fUp:0
WM_SYSKEYUP   nVirtKey:'A'     cRepeat:1 ScanCode:1E fExtended:0 AltDown:1 fRepeat:1 fUp:1
WM_KEYUP      nVirtKey:VK_MENU cRepeat:1 ScanCode:38 fExtended:0 AltDown:0 fRepeat:1 fUp:1
WM_CHAR       chCharCode:63    cRepeat:1 ScanCode:38 fExtended:0 AltDown:1 fRepeat:1 fUp:1
```

My debugger says `OnChar()` gets `nChar = 0x0000263a`, `nFlags = 0x0000c038`, `nRepCnt=1`.

How can I distinguish this code from a proper code like <kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>m</kbd> = µ on a German keyboard?

Comment: According to the [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/learnwin32/keyboard-input): Further, if the ALT key is held down, pressing the A key produces ALT+A, which the system does not treat as a character at all, but rather as a system command. I'm sorry I can't be sure what your code does, could you please show [a minimal, reproducible sample](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) without private information?

Comment: My minimal example behaves properly, so I have to find, why I'm getting such weird WM_CHAR messages in my real project.